# Rails Multiple Joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have four models: Encounters, Encounter_Vitals, Users, and Vital Types

- Encounters stores the Encounter Encounter Vitals stores an
- Encounter's Vitals and the user who took the Vitals Users has the
- Users who takes the vitals Vital Types is the different type of
- Vitals that could be taken

Encounters Model

```
has_many :encounter_vitals, foreign_key: "encounter_id"
...
Fields: ID, Date
```

Encounter Vital's Model

```
belongs_to :encounter
belongs_to :vital_type
belongs_to :user
...
Fields: ID, User ID, Encounter ID, Vital Type ID, Value
```

Users Model

```
has_many :encounters, foreign_key: "user_id"
has_many :encounter_vitals, foreign_key: "user_id"
...
Fields: ID, First Name, Last Name
```

Vital Types Model

```
has_many :encounter_vitals, foreign_key: "vital_type_id"
...
Fields: ID, Name
```

How do I get all of the Encounter Vital's for a specific encounter that shows the name of the vital, the value of the vital, and the user that entered the vital?

I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to work

```
@encounter = Encounter.find(1)
@encounter.joins(:encounter_vitals => {:vital_type, :user})
```

Answer (score 0):

The second line should have an array instead of a hash, try this instead:

```
@encounter = Encounter.joins(:encounter_vitals => [:vital_type, :user]).find(1)
```

Comment: This returns the following: `NoMethodError: undefined method joins for #<Encounter:0x007fb4226a15c0>`

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit quick. Try @encounter = Encounter.find(1).joins(:encounter_vitals => [:vital_type, :user])

Comment: Same thing as before. Is there something I need to change in the Encounter model?

Comment: Again sorry (I'm not in the flow today ;). It should be @encounter = Encounter.joins(:encounter_vitals => [:vital_type, :user]).find(1)